# Display a different message for virtual products in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I'm trying to display a message for virtual products in the cart that they will be processed in 1 to 3 days. I got this to display but it is also displaying the standard message treating it as a backorder.

Here is a portion of my `default.phtml`

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct() ?>
    <?php if ($_product->getTypeId() == "virtual"): ?>
    <p class="item-msg"><span class="fa fa-check"></span><?php echo $this->__('Item will be processed in 1 to 3 business days') ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($messages = $this->getMessages()): ?>
    <?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
        <p class="item-msg <?php echo $message['type'] ?>">* <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?></p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

How can I modify the above code to only show virtual products one message and other products the standard backorder message?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably leverage the existing messaging system here, shown in your snippet. You could do that using an observer. Assuming you have an extension to add this to already, it would be something like this:

**app/code/local/My/Extension/etc/config.xml**

Under the `config/frontend/events` node:

```
<sales_quote_item_set_product>
    <observers>
        <addVirtualProductNotice>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>My_Extension_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>addVirtualProductNotice</method>
        </addVirtualProductNotice>
    </observers>
</sales_quote_item_set_product>
```

**app/code/local/My/Extension/Model/Observer.php**

```
class My_Extension_Model_Observer
{
    public function addVirtualProductNotice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        if ($product->getIsVirtual()) {
            /* @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item */
            $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
            $message = Mage::getSingleton('core/message')->notice(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Item will be processed in 1 to 3 business days.'));
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addQuoteItemMessage($item->getId(), $message);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

To prevent virtual products from displaying the backorder message, I suggest setting the *Backorders* value to “Allow Qty Below 0” rather than “Allow Qty Below 0 and Notify Customer” under the *Inventory* tab of those products. It’s not clear whether you need to track the stock of these products at all, so if that is the case you could also just set *Manage Stock* to “No” on those products instead.